# data.table is copied when using spread()?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr

Here is a sample `data.table`.

```
set.seed(123)
mydt <- data.table(id = 1:100, x = sample(LETTERS[1:6], size = 100, replace = TRUE), group = paste0("group", sample(1:3, size = 100, replace = TRUE)), prob = runif(100, 0, 1))
```

I use `tydir::spread` to go from long to wide format

```
mydt2 <- mydt %>% spread(group, prob)
```

Then I want to define new columns as in

```
mydt2[!is.na(group1), new.col := x]
```

If I do this, I get the following warning

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(mydt2, !is.na(group1), `:=`(myscale, x)) :
 Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy
```

etc, while if I run this instead

```
mydt2 <- copy(mydt %>% spread(group, prob))
mydt2[!is.na(group1), myscale := x]
```

I don't get any warning. I don't understand this behaviour. Can anyone offer help? Is using `copy()` the right way to address this?

Comment: Title might not be very informative. Please update if so

Comment: `tidyr::spread` screws up the internal structure, which then `data.table` fixes (thus the warning); while the new `data.table` created during `copy` automatically has the correct internal structure. The internal structure here refers to pre-allocated memory for columns iirc.

Comment: I was surprised by this behaviour. I don't think `gather()` gives back a `data.table` for instance. Should I use `copy()` to avoid warning?

Comment: If you insist on using `spread`, then I'd just live with the warning. Alternatively use `dcast(mydt, id + x ~ group)`

Comment: "Then I want to define new columns as in" -- stick with data.table syntax or tidyverse syntax (with dtplyr); mixing and matching is not a good idea. With dplyr + dtplyr `mydt %>% tidyr::spread(group, prob) %>% mutate(new.col = replace(x, is.na(group1), NA))` works just fine.

Comment: Use `dcast` which is implemented for `data.table` instead. It's analogous to `spread`, and you shouldn't have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `dcast` is the way to go. However, a possible solution using `tidyr::spread` would be to add `setDT()` to the piped call, i.e.,

```
set.seed(123)

# install.packages(c("data.table"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(data.table)

mydt <- data.table(id = 1:100, x = sample(LETTERS[1:6], size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                   group = paste0("group", sample(1:3, size = 100, replace = TRUE)),
                   prob = runif(100, 0, 1)
                   )

class(mydt)
mydt2 <- mydt %>% tidyr::spread(group, prob) %>% setDT()

mydt2[!is.na(group1), new.col := x]
```